# Unable to paste passwords into Metro application password field

Tags: windows-8-preview

I am running Windows 8 Consumer Preview under VMWare Fusion Technology Preview and am unable to paste passwords into Mail Metro application password field. Also saw similar behavior in other metro application password fields.

Do all Metro apps not allows pasting passwords into password field?

Comment: Did you use the right-click content copy and paste options?

Answer (score 1):

Copy & Paste works fine for me (at least in Metro IE), but if what you're saying is actually true then I guess it could be some kind of security feature (preventing people from copy and pasting weak 
passwords or passwords that are obviously typed in/copied down somewhere).

To answer your question, I know for a fact that at least the Metro IE app allows copy & paste into a password field (just tried it :D)

UPDATE: I've tried the Mail app, and it works fine with copy & paste for passwords.